# How can I control lifecycle of extended class instances in Angular 2

Tags: class, angular, extend

In Angular 2.4.9 this code below does not work for me:

```
export class MyComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  type = 2;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log('inited type', this.type)
  }
}
```

meaning: there's no console output - regardless of whether `BaseComponent` implements `OnInit` or not.

If `BaseComponent` implements the hook though, then only its hooks are called, not the overriden one on `MyComponent`.

---

As the discussion proved that the plunker created alongside my description actually works, I managed to reproduce my problem in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/j1Ge1Qgs6NmclIBCDsJP?p=preview).

---

Is there any way to use lifecycle hooks in the extended class?

Comment: Do you use the component anywhere?

Comment: I use MyComponent on a page.

Comment: Working fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/etQL7rZXXnzo9VpnWbC8?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @echonax. You proved my desciription was not covering the actual problem. Please see the plnkr link that reproduces my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your `type` is never set so your `*ngIf`'s are not working.

According to the plunker you've provided, you need to provide the types in an `@Input`

**app template**

```
<base-comp [type]="1"></base-comp>
<base-comp [type]="2"></base-comp>
<base-comp [type]="1"></base-comp>
<base-comp [type]="2"></base-comp>
```

**BaseComponent field**

```
@Input() public type: number;
```

Fixed plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/B4dFDR1bgLI5kGgGrozE?p=preview

Comment: Yes, indeed, in the plnkr I forgot to actually implement the Input, but in my app I actually forgot to bracket it in html. BTW, is it the best way to do what I want to achieve here, ie. dynamically switch html template based on an input?

Comment: @nuton well since the components really have nothing in them, it's hard to tell :-) If the functionality is the same maybe you can check out the `ngSwitchCase` directive https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitchCase-directive.html.

Comment: I am using `ngSwitchCase` actually in my app, (`ngIf` was used here for brevity). I was just wondering if one could use TemplateRef in some way perhaps.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#interface-optional

Comment: @nuton glad I answered your question. It's been a tips and tricks section for me :P